# Dezzer Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a problem with a service provider Dezzer. I always listen to its music, and since i moved to a LTE connection i always get random buffer errors in chrome and Firefox

The message i get is Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Now my question is how coud i handle such an error? I know it is a server content length error but i already reported the bug to them several times and im fed up with it... but cant quit because the service is not bad and i have it as a part of my phone contract.

I googled it as far i can find but all sugest to repair the source (aka the server) but since Dezzer is taking it sweet time to do so i wanna make a chrome plugin to stuff their mouth and listen to some nice music :3

Comment: Dezzer? Did you mean Deezer? This really sounds like an error at their end, I don't think that you can fix it with a simple extension, because the Chrome extension does not reach that deep in the network layer.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo.  Hmmm is there a way via JS tht i can tellt hem in the bug report so they can slove it already ><` Because they are really lazy about it even with traces and all... Q_Q